# ActiveRecord and complex queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a 'Question' model.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end
```

...and an answer model...

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :answer_points
end
```

...and an Answer points model...

```
class AnswerPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :points
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :attribute
end
```

...and a user answer model...

```
class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :user
end
```

...and an attributes model.

```
class Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answer_points
end
```

Users answer questions, and each answer can have point values associated with a particular attribute. (ie. this answer gives 2 communication points, and one analytical, etc)

I want to display a list of the top 5-10 attributes generated by users answering questions. I know how to approach this from a raw SQL standpoint, but i'd prefer a more elegant, rails-y approach. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've settled on this:

```
questions = Question.where(:arbitrary_field => 'doge')
answers = Answer.where('question_id in (?)', questions.pluck(:id))
AnswerPoint.where('answer_id in (?)', answers.pluck(:id)).select('attribute_id, sum(points) as points').group('attribute_id').order('points desc')
```

It returns an AnswerPoint model for each unique attribute_id, and the points attribute contains the sum of points. Works for me, but I'm open to suggestion!